# Sorting Array by biggest number

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, 2d, comparator

This is my unsorted array:

```
P  B    A 
1  135  0
2  102  100
3  56   100
4  148  0
5  125  200
6  65   200
```

This is what my current array has after I sorted it this is the output I get

```
P  B    A 
1  135  0  
4  148  0  
3  56  100  
2  102  100  
6  65  200  
5  125  200
```

I want my array to sort `B` by the biggest number depending `A` like this example.

```
P  B    A 
4  148  0    
1  135  0  
2  102  100 
3  56  100  
5  125  200    
6  65  200
```

This is currently my code:

```
Arrays.sort(x, new Comparator<int[]>() {
    public int compare(int[] o1, int[] o2) {
        int ret = Integer.compare(o1[2], o2[2]);
        // if the entries are equal at index 2, compare index 1
        if (0 == ret) {
            ret = Integer.compare(o1[1], o2[1]);
        }
        return (ret);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just invert the comparison of `B` in the comparator:

```
if (ret == 0) {
    ret = Integer.compare(o2[1] , o1[1]);
}
```

Comment: but the `A` values are not from Longest  to small when is `A` a `100` for example

Comment: you have to insert my code into your comparator-class. just replace the `if`-block with the one from my answer

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, the second sorting criterion (the one for the first field) comes in the reverse order, so revert the comparison result (note the added `-` operator):

```
if (0 == ret) {
    ret = -Integer.compare(o1[1], o2[1]);
}
```

Comment: why so inefficient? just swap `o1[1]` with `o2[1]`. same result, no additional operations. i know, it's peanuts, but still

Comment: You're probably right, but in my opinion that thing is much easier to overlook than the `-` operator when reading the code. And, to be honest, there should be a distinct class for those data records that implements `Comparable`.